# Chrysanthemum blooms partially deformed and colors faded

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, flowers, container-gardening, flowering

I bought a potted Chrysanthemum from the local nursery over a month ago while the plant is still budding. Haven't repotted it since day 1. It bloomed very well couple weeks after I bought it and produce beautiful pink flowers.

However, I noticed that recently some of the blooms are deformed:

[image]
[image]

Here is the full pic of the pot:

[image]

The soil:
[image]

And the place where I put the whole container:
[image]

I usually water it once everyday or every 2 days, because the temp can get really hot in the afternoon. Since the balcony is west-facing, it received a hot afternoon sun around 1-5pm. However, with the placement in the pic above, the flower only receives 1-2 hrs of direct sun around 12pm (not the hottest period, as it peaked around 2-3) before getting some shade again (there is a roof in the balcony, and a house in front of mine). The situation looks like this in the afternoon (12pm):
[image]

The Place where I live doesn't have any winter. It only has sunny or rainy season. The temp never goes below 26'C and can get as high as 35'C in the hottest afternoon.

Also, I noticed that the color of the flowers faded. Is this a natural thing that mums color fades over the time? It once looks like this:
[image]

And suppose I wanted the plant to flowering again, should I start beheading the flower at this moment? All info and tips I found on the internet works for cold/subtropical area where it experiences winter, etc. But in my case, will it become annual or perennial??

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like botritis (sp) fungus. Try not to get the flowers and leaves wet when watering.